# Can't uninstall module from Drupal 7

Tags: 7

I'm running Drupal 7 from 2011-01-05 and I'm trying to uninstall Views Slideshow: Cycle (7.x-3.0 alpha1) and Views Slideshow(7.x-3.0-alpha1). I disabled them in the modules list then go to the uninstall list and uninstall them there but they still show up in the modules list and I can't re-install it because it says the modules are already installed.

I've tried clearing the cache.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To remove modules, you have to remove them from your server's modules directory (usually `sites/all/modules/`). Uninstalling through the interface runs the uninstall code provided in the module, typically to remove custom database data and tables that the module may have created.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Wasn't sure what the proper procedure was.

Answer (score 1):

1. Uncheck the module from your sites

   go to uninstall tab & check the modules you want to uninstall ->uninstall

2.
     go to sites/all/modules delete the module

3.
     go to the "database"-> "system" table -> search for that module row & delete
      (if the row exists)

4.
      clear the cache

Now it will be removed properly.